# To get IP addres of the specific host machine in rub

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I want to find the IP address of other system. For example, I am executing my code from server `wevrs1234` and I want the IP address of server `apvrs1234` and store it in variable. Please help me to get this.

```
ip = IPSocket.getaddress(Socket.gethostname)
```

is the code I have so far.

AS per suggestion i have made this code but getting error. Please find my code

```
 publish_vm = node['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['publish'].to_s
  nodes = search(:node, 'hostname:publish_vm')
 node.default['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['ip_address'] = 'nodes.first['ipaddress']'

  template node['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['owner']['home'] + '/conf.d/publish_farm.any' do
    source   'publish_farm.any.erb'
    owner    node['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['owner']['user']
    group    node['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['owner']['group']
    mode     '0755'
    variables(
      publish_host: node['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['publish'],
      publish_port: node['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['publish_port'],
      ip_addr: node['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['ip_address']
    )
  end
```

Error

```
[2020-05-20T06:09:52-05:00] DEBUG: Node wevrd64501.uhc.com loading cookbook aem_dispatcher_cookbook's attribute file /root/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/aem_dispatcher_cookbook/attributes/default.rb

================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /root/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/aem_dispatcher_cookbook/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================

SyntaxError
-----------
/root/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/aem_dispatcher_cookbook/recipes/default.rb:333: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
...ess'] = 'nodes.first['ipaddress']'
...                      ^~~~~~~~~

System Info:
```

Comment: Could you expand the question a bit with more info? Perhaps some code that you've tried. How these systems are connected. Why would you want to store the IP? is the IP static or dynamic? Is there a server running on the system you want IP of? If yes, then do you know the endpoint you could call? Do you want the public IP or internal IP?

Comment: ip = IPSocket.getaddress(Socket.gethostname)
    puts ip

Comment: I have used above code but the problem is it is taking same server from where i am running my code but i want to get ip from other server.I want to use this ip to update one file template in chef. IP is static. No i want to ip of other server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
publish_vm = node['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['publish'].to_s
  ruby_block 'get_ip_from_publish' do
    block do
      Chef::Resource::RubyBlock.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::ShellOut)
      command1 = "nslookup #{publish_vm} |grep '^Address' | awk '{print $2}'| tail -1"
      command_out = shell_out(command1)
      node.run_state['master_ip'] = command_out.stdout
    end
    action :run
  end
```

This piece of code helped me to get ip address of desired host machine

Answer (score 0):

You tagged the question with [chef] and [chef-recipe], so I understand you are trying to get another machine's IP address inside recipe. If that another machine is also registered with Chef Server, the easiest would be [`search`](https://docs.chef.io/chef_search/). You can search for any machine registered on the Chef Server by some attribute, in your case - hostname.

```rb
nodes = search(:node, 'hostname:<another_vm_hostname>')
p nodes.first['ipaddress']
```

*Update*:

You have an error in your 3rd line. Don't surround `nodes.first['ipaddess']` with quotes.

```rb
 node.default['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['ip_address'] = nodes.first['ipaddress']
```

Comment: Is it p  nodes.first['ipaddress']?

Comment: Search returns an array, so `nodes.first['ipaddress']` will give you the ip address of the first found node.

Comment: nodes = search(:node, 'hostname:node['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['publish']')

  template node['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['owner']['home'] + '/conf.d/publish_farm.any' do
    source   'publish_farm.any.erb'
    owner    node['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['owner']['user']
    group    node['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['owner']['group']
    mode     '0755'
    variables(
      publish_host : node['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['publish'],
      publish_port : default['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['publish_port'],
      ip_addr : nodes.first['ipaddress']
    )
  end

Comment: Update your question, with your new code and error message.

Comment: Please check my code and error which i am getting will it work to get ip of other VM which i am trying

Comment: If i am putting this in 'nodes.first['ipaddress']' double quotes it is replacing like this

Comment: After puting this line ```node.default['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['ip_address'] = nodes.first['ipaddress']

Comment: ```node.default['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['ip_address'] = nodes.first('ipaddress').to_i
``` I have tried this getting this error ``` Recipe Compile Error in /root/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/aem_dispatcher_cookbook/recipes/default.rb
  ================================================================================

  TypeError
  ---------
  no implicit conversion of String into Integer
``` getting same result with .to_i or without